# Export and Append Data to CSV

Tags: t-sql, export-to-csv

I am trying to export data to existing csv file.

I have been using these methods to export data.

- Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0
- SQLCMD
- Data Export Wizard

However I cannot find if there is any parameter / option to append the exported data to existing file. Is there any way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note: answer is biased towards *nix operating systems; I'm not too familiar with windows.

If you can run your sql query via the command line,

- using a scripting language, you can use a library that creates an `MSSQL` connection, (an example of this is a `node.js` program I authored (https://github.com/skilbjo/aqtl but any tool will do), or
- a windows binary that runs something like `sqlcmd` from the command line,

you can just pipe the output to the csv file. For example:

```
$ node runquery.js myquery.sql >> existing_csv_file.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Right it's pretty straight forward if it can be done in a program. Just wonder if there's any built-in function in query or management studio so I can set up db job straight for the export.

Comment: Not likely as I imagine that's not a common use case. Best of luck though finding an answer through an existing tool!